# Can't inspect elements on IE browser - Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm testing a CRM web application and in some point there is a pop up comes to screen(after clicking an element).
this pop also called "webpage dialog". for some reason, when this pop up shown on screen, I'm unable to use the F12(developers) in order to inspect elements.
I'll be happy to have your assitance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you have to do is disabling the security option "Allow websites to open windows without address or status bars".

on internet Explorer, Open :  Tools-->Internet options-->Security-->Custom Level --> Miscellaneous --> Allow websites to open windows without address or status bars-->  Disable.

and you will be able to inspect your modal dialogs on IE

Hope It helps,
Haythem